# Firebase RealTime Database con Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, real-time

Estoy haciendo una aplicación android y una base de datos en Firebase pero cuando agrego la instancia la aplicación no se ejecuta solo se cierra.

```
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference.child("1").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                String nombre=dataSnapshot.child("nombre").getValue().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),nombre,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Qué error te muestra en el log?

Comment: @crrlos No da error, compilo el proyecto y se instala correctamente en el dispositivo pero cuando abre de inmediato se cierra la aplicación

Comment: @crrlos ahora me lanza este error: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$IdTokenListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebaseexample-lhNvMTtOcG9jKxarUnWYWg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.firebaseexample-lhNvMTtOcG9jKxarUnWYWg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualiza la versión de la biblioteca

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
```